# How to convert .m4a to .mp3 in either PHP or Python

Tags: php, python, mp3, m4a

I am making a YouTube MP3 download site for personal, family and some close friends to use. So far, I have got as far as getting the source location, downloading the file, but then I hit a barrier, It downloads in .m4a format. AFAICT WMV is unable to play MPEG-4 Audio files, I know it is downloading correctly becuase when I drag it into FF it plays the file, but I need to have it in .mp3 format, and I need to do it in either PHP or Python. 

I just need to know at a minimum where to look to get started on this, since much of the things I have come across, either confuse me excessivly or simply don't work. Like stated in the title, I can use either PHP 5.5.12 or python 3.4 to get the job done, since both of these are already in use.

Comment: how are you downloading?

Comment: I'm using the python module [pafy](https://github.com/np1/pafy)'s .download function to download the file to the web directory, which with some AJAX magic presents the user with a link, but M4A is seemingly unsupported by WMP, and I would rather an .MP3 for wider usability anyway.

Comment: Sorry, @PadraicCunningham I forgot to tag you in the first comment :/

Comment: I was going to suggest subprocess and ffmpeg in python.  The answers in the dup are pretty poor but hopefully  will set you on the right path.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think I might be getting somewhere, but I really hate having to use command line code for things, always un-nerves me, I was hoping that I would get a library thrown at my face.

Comment: http://mikeboers.github.io/PyAV/ https://pypi.python.org/pypi/av/0.1.0 https://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/